# Using Java with OpenCV and Mask_RCNN

Tags: java, opencv, reshape, mask, mat

I've had a lot of experience with Java, and have already written my own utilities for processing imagery. I realise that there are many tutorials out there for Python, but I'm much more inclined to use Java as I would like to integrate some of the facilities of OpenCV 4.1 with my existing Java code. 
One of my experiments is to try and obtain the masks of objects identified ion images using the coco dataset

```
// Give the textGraph and weight files for the model
private static final String TEXT_GRAPH = "models/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.pbtxt";
private static final String MODEL_WEIGHTS = "models/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb";
private static final String CLASSES_FILE = "models/mscoco_labels.names";

TextFileConsumer consumer = new TextFileConsumer();
File textFile = new File(CLASSES_FILE);
if (textFile.exists()){
    BufferedReader fr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
    fr1.lines().forEach(consumer::storeLines);
}
String[] CLASSES = consumer.lines.toArray(new String[0]);
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("images/bird.jpg");
Size size = image.size();
int cols = image.cols();
int rows = image.rows();
double h = size.height;
double w = size.width;
int hh = (int)size.height;
int ww = (int)size.width;
Mat blob = org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0,  new Size(w, h), Scalar.all(0), true, false);

// Load the network
Net net = org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODEL_WEIGHTS, TEXT_GRAPH);
net.setPreferableBackend(org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
net.setPreferableTarget(org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU);
net.setInput(blob);
ArrayList<String> outputlayers = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Mat> outputMats = new ArrayList<Mat>();
outputlayers.add("detection_out_final");
outputlayers.add("detection_masks");
net.forward(outputMats,outputlayers);
Mat numClasses = outputMats.get(0);
numClasses = numClasses.reshape(1, (int)numClasses.total() / 7);

for (int i = 0; i < numClasses.rows(); ++i) {
    double confidence = numClasses.get(i, 2)[0];
    //System.out.println(confidence);
    if (confidence > 0.2) {
        int classId = (int) numClasses.get(i, 1)[0];
        String label = CLASSES[classId] + ": " + confidence;
        System.out.println(label);
        int left   = (int)(numClasses.get(i, 3)[0] * cols);
        int top    = (int)(numClasses.get(i, 4)[0] * rows);
        int right  = (int)(numClasses.get(i, 5)[0] * cols);
        int bottom = (int)(numClasses.get(i, 6)[0] * rows);
        System.out.println(left + " " + top + " " + right + " " + bottom);
    }
}
Mat numMasks = outputMats.get(1);
```

So far so good. My problem now is trying to obtain the segmentation shapes from numMasks Mat. 
The size gives 90x100, total 2025000 and type -1*-1*CV_32FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=true.
I know I have to reshape too, perhaps like this:

`numMasks = numMasks.reshape(1, (int)numMasks.total() / 90);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Further edit
I think the masks are 15 x 15. 
90 x 100 x 15 x 15 gives 2025000 so that gives me the total I saw earlier so I need to resize a mask and mix with original image.

Comment: I might be onto something with this
`Mat reshape = numMasks.reshape(1,  (int)(numMasks.total()/(15*15)));

Mat rfound = reshape.row(classId*100);

rfound = rfound.reshape(1,15);`

Comment: So the answer to obtaining correct mask appears to be this:
`//This will return a 9000 * 225 matrix
Mat reshape = numMasks.reshape(1, (int) (numMasks.total() / (15 * 15)));
System.out.println("reshape " + reshape);
//find appropriate class
Mat rfound = reshape.row((i * 100) + classId);
System.out.println("(i * 100) + classId " + rfound);
//get a 1 x 225 mask if necessary
rfound = rfound.reshape(1,225);
System.out.println("rfound.reshape(1,225) 1st " + rfound);
//or shape to 15 x 15
rfound = rfound.reshape(1, 15);
System.out.println("rfound.reshape(1,15) 2nd " + rfound);
`

Comment: Did also display the mask? I'm, using your code but Image is all black.
Mat reshape = numMasks.reshape(1, (int) (numMasks.total() / (15 * 15)));
            System.out.println("reshape " + reshape);
            reshape.convertTo(reshape,CV_8UC3);
            reshape.copyTo(dnnTarget);
HighGui.imshow("CNN",dnnTarget);